# What is the cause of the error - Rendering ID was not present in the rendered renderings context?

Tags: jss

I am getting a strange error when deploying a `JSS` application to Sitecore and running in Integrated mode.

> Rendering data contained rendering reference ID
>   6cc52330-7130-49a8-9585-5b9b8d946847 but that rendering ID was not
>   present in the rendered renderings context. This ought not to occur.
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Rendering data contained rendering
>   reference ID 6cc52330-7130-49a8-9585-5b9b8d946847 but that rendering
>   ID was not present in the rendered renderings context. This ought not
>   to occur.]
>   Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.PlaceholderRenderingService.ConvertRenderedPlaceholderMarkup(RenderedPlaceholder
>   placeholder, String contents, RenderedJsonRenderingContext
>   renderedRenderingContext)
>   +969Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.PlaceholderRenderingService.RenderPlaceholder(PlaceholderDefinition
>   placeholderDefinition, IRenderingConfiguration renderingConfiguration)
>   +499   System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +117   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +124
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +436

This seems to be related to cache. If I clear the cache via `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` the next page refesh will work. Any subsequent page refresh will fail again after the first load and the Rendering ID in the error message changes.

Any hints on the source of the issue are appreciated.

Comment: Is there any component with a placeholder in it which is cache'able?

Comment: Yes, a single component on the page has Rendering cache turned on with Vary By Data. The component does not contain any placeholders though.    The component simply renders a banner image.

Comment: And if you disable cache, does the error still exist?

Comment: The issue goes away once cache for the rendering is turned off.   This is a pretty simple component with just an image and it lives inside the default JSS placeholder "jss-main".

Comment: Source HTML:  `<sc-placeholder name="jss-main" ng-reflect-name="jss-main" ng-reflect-rendering="[object Object]">

<app-banner><hr><a href="https://www.sitecore.com" text="Link to Sitecore" url="https://www.sitecore.com" linktype="external">
<img class="img-fluid" sizes="(min-width: 639px) 640px, (max-width: 1024px) 1025px, (max-width: 1440px) 1441px, 1920px" alt="Sitecore JSS Logo" width="1600" height="275" style="margin: 0px 0px" srcset="http://jssangularweb/-/jssmedia/JssAngularWeb/data/media/img/tweaked.jpg?mw=640 640w">
</a><hr></app-banner></sc-placeholder>`

Comment: I guess my questions is now should rendering cache settings be used at all with JSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore SXA versions up to 1.8 is not compatible with Sitecore JSS 11.0. And, with the release of SXA 1.9 and JSS 12, those 2 are now compatible.

However, the above issue is still present. I have opened a Sitecore Support ticket and they acknowledge that this is a bug and already recorded them into their Bug Tracking System.

**Sitecore Patch**

Sitecore provided me a patch with public reference `322824` and contained 2 files

```
Sitecore.Support.Diagnostic.539647.config

Sitecore.Support.Diagnostic.539647.dll
```

The config file should be placed in the `App_Config/Include/zzz` folder so that it is loaded in the end.

You can have more information on my blog here: [Sitecore SXA JSS Cache fix](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2019/09/10/sitecore-sxa-jss-cache-error-fix/)

Sitecore no longer provides patches for Sitecore 9.1 and later according to [Sitecore Versioning Policy](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/077333). But you'll still need to have a Sitecore Support ticket for them to provide you the patch.

The patch will/should be removed when a newer version of SXA is released.